# Could ES support Surround query parser?

Tags: elasticsearch, lucene, query-parser

Could I change ES query parser to support "Surround query parser".

`org.apache.lucene.queryParser.surround.parser.QueryParser`

and do something mentioned in 
[query parser](https://lucidworks.com/blog/2009/02/22/exploring-query-parsers/)

```
99w(aa,bb,cc)
99n(aa,bb,cc)
```

or something mentioned
[here](http://www.gossamer-threads.com/lists/lucene/java-user/93536)

```
(spot w prices) 3w (gulf w coast)
```

Or could some other way to do this in ES?
I am new to SearchEngine.
Any sugguestion would be appreicated.

Comment: There is an [open issue](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/issues/11328) about this, but it hasn't gotten a lot of attention so far. Maybe comment it and +1 it so it gets on the radar again...

Comment: Ok, I have no way but to write this feature as a parser plugin, and install it.

Comment: Ok, I write a Parser for this, just to work for our product.
I am new to ES parser and Lucene, the example code is not so good, But it did work for me.
https://github.com/bairongdong1/BayParser